# How to convert string to integer in JES

Tags: jython-2.5, jes

I am trying to do an assignment in JES a student jython program. I need to convert our student number taken as a string input variable to pass through our function i.e. 
def assignment(stringID) and convert it into integers. The exact instructions are:

Step 1
Define an array called id which will store your 7 digit number as integers (the numbers you set in the array does not matter, it will be over written with your student number in the next step).
Step 2 Your student number has been passed in to your function as a String. You must separate the digits and assign them to your array id. This can do this manually line by line or using a loop. You will need to type cast each character from stringID to an integer before storing it in id.

I have tried so many different ways using the int and float functions but I am really stuck.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "545.2222"

>>> float(a)

545.22220000000004

>>> int(float(a))

545
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have tried this but my code still wouldn't work. We had to define an array for our id and then change the stringID variable from a characters into integers and assign them to the array. I've tried it this way too:def assignment1(stringID):
  id = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  stringID = ((int(stringID[0])), (int(stringID[1])), (int(stringID[2])), (int(stringID[3])), (int(stringID[4])), (int(stringID[5])), (int(stringID[6])))
  id = stringID

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some jython scripting for a websphere server. It must be a really old version of python it didn't have the ** operator or the len() function. I had to use an exception to find the end of a string.

Anyways I hope this saves someone else some time

```
def pow(x, y):
    total = 1;
    if (y > 0):
        rng = y
    else:
        rng = -1 * y

    print ("range", rng)
    for itt in range (rng):
        total *= x

    if (y < 0):
        total = 1.0 / float(total)
    return total

#This will return an int if the percision restricts it from parsing decimal places
def parseNum(string, percision):
    decIndex = string.index(".")
    total = 0
    print("decIndex: ", decIndex)
    index = 0
    string = string[0:decIndex] + string[decIndex + 1:]
    try:
        while string[index]:
            if (ord(string[index]) >= ord("0") and ord(string[index]) <= ord("9")):
                times = pow(10, decIndex - index - 1)
                val = ord(string[index]) - ord("0")
                print(times, " X ", val)
                if (times < percision):
                    break
                total += times * val
            index += 1
    except:
        print "broke out"
    return total
```

**Warning!** - make sure the string is a number. The function will not fail but you will get strange and almost assuredly, useless output.